# How do you manage a Scala application without a building tool?

Tags: scala, sbt

How does one manually maintain dependencies and run a Scala application without SBT or another build tool?

Running `scala app.scala` results in error finding any imports and dependencies.

Is this even possible or is SBT (or cousins) required for every single project that has dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of anyone trying to manage the dependency hell manually for anything non-trivial.
If you want to manage dependencies, you need some kind of tool to do it.
If you find `sbt` too heavyweight, try [Ammonite](http://ammonite.io/#IvyDependencies) which supports scripts with ivy-dependencies.

Comment: I guess I'll have to learn to use sbt. Thanks for the Ammonite link, though I completely fail to see the usefulness of the Ammonite project, which seems to be addressing several somewhat unrelated (non)issues.

Answer (score 7):

> How does one manually maintain dependencies and run a Scala application without SBT or another build tool?

With a lot of difficulty, just like in Java. You need to find all transitive dependencies (i.e. direct dependencies, their dependencies, *their* dependencies etc.) manually (or using the build tool just for that), download their jars, and run `scala -classpath … app.scala` (where the argument to `-classpath` enumerates all jars with correct OS-dependent separator). Or `scalac …` and then `java -classpath … MainClassName` (in this case `-classpath` will need to include the Scala runtime library, which `scala` command implies).